# serve_site() in blogdown un-deletes old files

Tags: rstudio, hugo, blogdown

I built a site using blogdown in Rstudio. I'm not sure if I am experiencing a bug or if this is expected, but it is kind of annoying, and I'm wondering if I can fix it.

When I use

```
serve_site()
```

All of the old file folders I deleted come back in my public folder.

My current set up is with the Lithium theme, and I make several test documents and folders to test the linking. When I make .Rmd files in the content folder in particular, it will create a folder with that name in the Public folder as well as that name_files.

After I delete the test folders and test file folders, the test file folders come back after I use the serve_site() function in Rstudio.

Example:

1) Add "Example.Rmd" to the content folder

2) Automatically an "Example" folder is added to the Public folder with the index.html

3) Automatically an "Example_files" folder is added to the Public folder with the related files

4) After testing I delete the Example.Rmd, Example Folder from the public folder, Example_files folder from Public

5) After using serve_site() in Rstudio, the "Example_files" folder comes back - I cannot delete it!

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for `*_files` directories under the `static/` directory (under your website's root directory) and delete them there.

Comment: Got it! thanks - also Blogdown is amazing. Thank you for creating